# How to perform bonding with BLE device in Flutter

Tags: flutter, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

I'm using flutter_blue plugin to communicate with the BLE device. The problem here is the pairing request popup every time connecting to the device. This happens due to the fact that the plugin actually never bonds to the device and makes pairing requests every time the app is launched.

My question is: Is there any way to perform a bonding with BLE device or at least a way to pass the pairing request popup without the user interaction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like bonding is not implemented in Flutter Blue. I suggest you log an issue on the github page of that plugin.